# customize context menu of webview in windows8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, webview

In webview control, we can select contents and right click to call the context menu, there's only a 'copy' option, I want to add my custom items into the context menu, but I found it seems not possible from this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/winappswithcsharp/thread/20c05893-d26f-474e-88b9-b42800071ccb. Is it possible to disable the native context menu and create my own context menu for the webview?